# Why use #define DEF ((unsigned) -1) instead of #define 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, unsigned

In the **C** language, why use the following line to define a constant with all bits set to 1?:

```
#define EXTENDED_MEM_END    ((unsigned) -1)
```

Instead of using the following?:

```
#define EXTENDED_MEM_END    0xFFFFFFFF
```

Or just this?:

```
#define EXTENDED_MEM_END    -1
```

**Does it have something to do with portability (i.e., avoiding warnings), with a very specific code, and/or something else?**

I suspect that, since the **C** code is going to have the **EXTENDED_MEM_END** identifier replaced by `((unsigned) -1)`, it is in fact a way to use the correct/expected value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define EXTENDED_MEM_END    0xFFFFFFFF
```

isn't right if ints aren't 32 bits;

```
#define EXTENDED_MEM_END    -1
```

isn't unsigned.

Comment: @R.. I just answered the OP's question of what's wrong with the alternatives. There are numerous ways to express the correct value ... yours being the shortest, but UINT_MAX might be clearer (though that Minix code probably predates stdint.h).

Comment: By the way, on a related note, I finally found a use for `sizeof(char)`: `-sizeof(char)` is a portable way to get `SIZE_MAX`, aka `(size_t)-1`, without depending on any headers being included.

Comment: @R.. That's a fun fact, but I'll continue to use meaningful names and include headers. :-)

Comment: @JimBalter, `(size_t)-1` kind of works in `#if`, at least it is a number for the preprocessor. `(size_t)-1U` would work where the width of `uintmax_t` and `size_t` are the same.

Comment: @JimBalter, yes it is a number for the preprocessor. Any identifier that the preprocessor doesn't know about is replaced by `0` in `#if` evaluations. So that translates to `(0)-1` which a valid expression. In turn `-sizeof(char)` becomes `-0(0)` in the preprocessor, which isn't a valid expression.

Comment: @JimBalter, that wasn't meant to offend you or anything. This *is* a valid trick that can come handy some times when you'd have to ensure that generic constants are the right thing in different contexts. E.g something like `(uintmax_t)-5U` would really work (even in your restricted sense of the word "work") in places where you'd need something like that.

Comment: @JimBalter, but now you offended me.

Answer (score 1):

On a 32-bit machine, trying to define 64 1-bits will overflow, and give a warning -- but on a 64-bit machine, defining only 32 1-bits will give the wrong value.

`((unsigned)-1)` will produce the correct result under *all* circumstances (it's required by the standard).

Comment: @JimBalter Read the last sentence - *it's required by the standard*. Wrap-around behavior for unsigned integers is well defined regardless of the bit representation.

Comment: Assuming `unsigned int` has 32 value bits, `0xffffffff` will give the correct value. I'm confused why you think it wouldn't. The issue is cleanliness or portability to machines where the type is larger/smaller, not anything to do with ones complement or sign/magnitude.

Comment: @R..: You're right about one's complement and sign/magnitude -- not sure what I was thinking of there.

Comment: @R.. He said you're right ... that's why he edited it out. Maybe you read "not sure what I was thinking of" and thought "I" referred to yourself?

Comment: He edited that comment after I replied to it too (see the pencil icon).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `UINT_MAX` from `<limits.h>` .
This will be portable. The other alternatives fail on different architectures `((unsigned)-1)` (fails on non-two's complement architectures (not that you'll have that problem much in practice)) or `0xffffffff` (fails on 64-bit architectures) or `0xffffffffffffffff` (fails on 32-bit architectures).

Comment: The OP isn't looking for more alternatives ... the question is about why specific alternatives weren't used.

Answer (score 1):

For a 32 bit OS , -1 is same as 0xFFFFFFFF but for a 64 bit OS ,0xFFFFFFFF is considered as 0x00000000FFFFFFFF, so it value is not -1 but a high positive value.